# Finite potential well and nature of its solutions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

The question I have is about nature of solutions, not a solution or a specific answer that I am looking for. If we define a potential well centred at $x=0$ as the following,
$$V(x) = \left\{  \begin{array}{lr} -V_{0} &  : |x| < L\\ 0 &  : |x| > L \end{array} \right.$$

where $V_{0}$ is a real, positive number. Given that the particle is in an energy eigenstate inside the well, with some energy $E$ such that $-V_{0} < E < 0$, what can we say about the form of the wave inside the well region?

I struggling with the concept to find a solution to such case. I know the solutions should have an exponential decay at the ends and for $E$, $k=\sqrt{2mE/\hbar^2}$ and so I would assume the wave would propagate to the right, however the conditions are set so that $V(x)$ has to be smaller than 0 while being greater than $-V_0$, hence the confusion. What would the nature of the solutions be? Would the wave go to the right, or sum of them propagating to both left and right? Perhaps it would exponentially decay? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're solving Schrödinger's equation with the second derivative for the kinetic energy.  Because the energy $E$ is within the range $-V_0 < E < 0$, then outside the well, for $|x| > L$, the solution is exponential decay (as $E < V(|x| > L)$), and inside the well the solution is oscillatory (as $E > V(|x| < L)$).  The wave function and its derivative must be continuous at the boundary.

$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
A e^{ikx} + Be^{-ikx},~~k = \sqrt{2m(E+V_0)/\hbar^2},~~|x| < L \\
C e^{\kappa x} + De^{-\kappa x},~~\kappa = \sqrt{-2mE/\hbar^2},~~|x| > L \\
\end{cases}.$$ You can verify these solutions work by plugging them into the Schrödinger equation.

Inside the well, the most general solution for the bound state will be a linear combination of the left and right propagating modes, a standing wave.  You can solve for $A$ and $B$ the old-fashioned way by matching boundary conditions, or you can use inversion symmetry.  Note the potential (and kinetic term) is invariant under inversion $I: x \rightarrow -x$, which reflects about the origin.  Because inversion squares to $1$ (the identity), its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, so the wavefunction is either even or odd under inversion.  Hence $A = B$ or $A = -B$, and the wave function inside the well is a sine or a cosine.

Comment: you might care to add that the matching condition will result in a transcendental equation for $E$ via $k$ and $\kappa$, and this must be solved numerically in general.

Comment: I understand, thank you so much! Another question in my mind would be what kind of solutions would we observe in the region x > L? Would they decay exponentially?